# Slicing results of Django Query into Sets of 10

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, split, slice

I have a `class I` and another `class X`

**class X:**

```
class X(I):
    userUrls = self.loadGivenDomainPaths

    def compute_path_amount(self):
        if count(userUrls) > 10:
            #try:
                #Slice urls into list of 10s from userUrls
            #except:
                #error occurred.
        else:
            #blah
```

How do code the `try()` block above to Slice the results of `loadGivenDomainPaths` as defined as:

```
PathsOfDomain.objects.filter(TheFK=user, a=True)
```

I want to slice results into sets of 10 results (each result is a `string`) a `dictionary` could possibly work, just at a bit of loss for syntax here.

**Update** I've also thought about some way to use a `for()` loop to count 10 objects (from the django query like:

```
def get_10_paths(self):
    for obj in domainPaths:
        return objs
```

The problem is this would only return an object at a time, not a set of 10. I'm rather confused on how to approach this still

Any helpful code snippets, suggestions, and/or links would be helpful.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks ?

Comment: This isn't getting the values from a Django Orm Objects

Comment: As long as it's an `iterable` - it doesn't matter

Comment: Can you write an answer of how I might accomplish this? Would really appreciate it . The link you gave me is for P2.6

Comment: I don't have time - you can adapt [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/434411/1252759) answer from the link though... if not - I'm sure someone will come along sooner rather than later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can combine slicing with for loop:

```
def compute_path_amount(self):
    return [
        self.__class__.userUrls[i:i+9] for i in xrange(
            0, len(self.__class__.userUrls), 10
        )
    ]
```

Comment: So, this returns sets of 10s of userUrls ?

Comment: Yes, it returns a list of lists (each of them is of length 10 - except for the last one which might be shorter).